# How to write a for loop which creates a model and has a function which references that same model

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr, anova

I am trying to run a post hoc analysis on an unbalanced two way anova using the `anova_test` funciton in the `rstatix` package. I need to run this post hoc test iteratively, as I have ~26 response (y) variables. My first step is to create models of all my `y` variables with relation to `group` and `treatment`. I have successfully managed to do this, creating a single list with 26 models:

`models <- map(data[,y1:y26], ~(lm(.x ~data$group*data$treatment)))`

Now comes the part I'm stuck on. Referring to these models iteratively. I would like to run the following code for *every* `y` variable I have:

```
group_by(group) %>%
anova_test(y ~ treatment, error = models(y), type = 3)
```

where my `y` changes every time and as it does, the "model" (referred to in the `error =` term) is updated accordingly. I'm struggling with this bit since first set of models I make is used to inform the second set of models.

However, if I run just one `y` variable through this whole bit of code at one time, I get the appropriate results.

```
model <- lm(y ~ group*treatment, data = data)

data %>%
group_by(group) %>%
anova_test(y ~ treatment, error = model, type = 3)
```

I have tried creating a for loop as well as using the `map` function in the `purrr` package but I have been unsuccessful. I am new to for loops and `purrr` so I am sure it's a simple fix I just can't see it.

Basically I want a way to run

```
data %>%
group_by(group) %>%
anova_test(y ~ treatment, error = model, type = 3)
```

iteratively for different `y` variables (`y1, y2, ..., y26`) while also referring to the approprite `model` (model$y1, model$y2, ..., model$26).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should all models be of the form `model <- lm(y ~ x1 * X)`, where you want to plug in `x3, x4, ..., x26`?

Comment: I want to plug in different response variables, so I would plug in `y1, y2, y3, ..., y26`. Sorry for the confusion @thorepet.

Comment: Same independents every time such different dependent for each?

Comment: Same independents every time. Only the `y` variable will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nirgrahamuk from the rstudio community forum for this answer:

```r
map(names(models_1) ,
    ~ anova_test(data=group_by(df,edge),
                 formula = as.formula(paste0(.x,"~ trt")),
                 error = models_1[[.x]],
                 type = 3))
```

(see their full answer at: https://community.rstudio.com/t/trouble-using-group-by-and-map2-together/66730/8?u=mvula)

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Well you didn't give any data so let's use toothgrowth.  You seem to like the model format, so let's build a list of models.  You could do this in an automated fashion but to make it clear lets do it by hand.  The call `purrr::map` with the `anova_test` function.  You'll get a list back.  Since you're in charge of naming the list elements go to town.

Updated answer May 18th.  Now using `map2` since you want two different models passed build a list for each...

```r
library(rstatix)
library(purrr)

ToothGrowth$len2 <- ToothGrowth$len^2 # for variety

models <- list(model1 = lm(len ~ supp*dose, ToothGrowth), 
               model2 = lm(len ~ dose*supp, ToothGrowth),
               model3 = lm(len2 ~ dose*supp, ToothGrowth),
               model4 = lm(len2 ~ supp*dose, ToothGrowth))

models2 <- list(model1 = lm(len ~ supp, ToothGrowth), 
               model2 = lm(len ~ dose, ToothGrowth),
               model3 = lm(len2 ~ dose, ToothGrowth),
               model4 = lm(len2 ~ supp, ToothGrowth))


# one model
purrr::map(models, ~ anova_test(.x, type = 3))


# now with model for error term
purrr::map2(models, models2, ~ anova_test(.x, error = .y, type = 3))
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#> $model1
#> ANOVA Table (type III tests)
#> 
#>      Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
#> 1      supp   1  58  4.058 0.049000     * 0.065
#> 2      dose   1  58 12.717 0.000734     * 0.180
#> 3 supp:dose   1  58  1.588 0.213000       0.027
#> 
#> $model2
#> ANOVA Table (type III tests)
#> 
#>      Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
#> 1      dose   1  58 33.626 2.92e-07     * 0.367
#> 2      supp   1  58 10.729 2.00e-03     * 0.156
#> 3 dose:supp   1  58  4.200 4.50e-02     * 0.068
#> 
#> $model3
#> ANOVA Table (type III tests)
#> 
#>      Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
#> 1      dose   1  58 36.028 1.35e-07     * 0.383
#> 2      supp   1  58  7.128 1.00e-02     * 0.109
#> 3 dose:supp   1  58  2.709 1.05e-01       0.045
#> 
#> $model4
#> ANOVA Table (type III tests)
#> 
#>      Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
#> 1      supp   1  58  2.684 0.107000       0.044
#> 2      dose   1  58 13.566 0.000508     * 0.190
#> 3 supp:dose   1  58  1.020 0.317000       0.017
```

Comment: Thanks @ChuckP! My question was poorly worded (I've edited accordingly). I have successfully run the code you suggested, but it is the second portion of the code which _refers_ to these models (via the "error = model" clause) that I am struggling with. `data %>% group_by(group) %>%
anova_test(y ~ treatment, error = model, type = 3)'

Comment: You've totally lost me. `data` is your original data (which you still haven't shown.  What and where is `group`?  If you want the post hocs why not `purrr::map(models, ~ tukey_hsd(.x))`

Comment: I've updated the question yet again to be more specific (I've been working on this most of the day and got lost in my own head - sorry!). As for providing data, I am happy do do so but don't know how as this is my first question I've posted. With regards to post hocs, I thought that because the anova was unbalanced a TukeyHSD was inappropriate... is that incorrect? (I know this isn't a stats forum, so I'll dig into this question elsewhere)

Comment: Right but I don't think the `error =` does what you think it does and it makes no sense to have it be the same formula as the formula for the model you're testing.  If you want more conservative post hoc we can do Games Howell with map as well or use the t_test function in the package but in none of those cases do you use `error`.  As to which I like holm which is typically the default and when coupled with Welchs is pretty conservative but Games Howell is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the stats advice! I'll look into those options. However, just for my own edification, I would still like to know how to code this as per my original question. I am using two different formulas, where one formula builds model A while a second formula builds model B but has the error rate reported from model A (thus model A is used in representing model B). This may be incorrect stats wise, but I see broader applications here...

Comment: Well to be fair your questions has changed repeatedly over time LOL.  Okay so this is key new information you actually have a model_a and a model B both specified by formula.  I'll edit the answer again but spoiler alert build two lists and use `map2`

Comment: Thanks@Chuck P - I have tried `map2` and come upon another problem which I have posted as a new question, complete with `reprex`. Didn't mean to abandon the post, just seemed like it had drifted from my initial question here